# linux + dose each security kernel rpm will install the relevant initrd and vmlinuz files under /boot

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, kernel

I just print the kernel rpms that need to install on my redhat machine (version 6.5)

# yum list-security --security | grep kernel-[0-9]

```
    RHSA-2014:1143 security kernel-2.6.18-371.12.1.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2014:1959 security kernel-2.6.18-400.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2014:2008 security kernel-2.6.18-400.1.1.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2015:0164 security kernel-2.6.18-402.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2015:0783 security kernel-2.6.18-404.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2015:1042 security kernel-2.6.18-406.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2016:0045 security kernel-2.6.18-408.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2016:0450 security kernel-2.6.18-409.el5.x86_64
```

in case I want to install all  security kernel rpms ( as displayed )
is that mean that all 8 (initrd & vmlinuz) kernels files will be installed under /boot ?

I am asking this question because I have small free available size on /boot

remark - the yum command that installed all the security packages is:

```
     yum -y update --security
```

example what I have now under /boot:

```
# ls /boot
   System.map-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5  grub                             lost+found                      vmlinuz-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5
   config-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5      initrd-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5.img  symvers-   2.6.18-371.11.1.el5.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all 8 will be installed in /boot

I would recommend installing them in groups and once You boot from newer kernel move old one to archive as You might need it maybe in the future.

Comment: after installation (yum -y update --security)  I see that only the latest kernel was installed - kernel-2.6.18-409.el5.x86_64 , how it can be ?

Comment: where are all the  list , why I not see the other kernels (no under /boot ) and no in grub.conf ?? , whats happend here ?

Comment: well I have to say that I'm puzzled, have You rebooted after upgrade? Is the new kernel loaded?

Comment: I not reboot the OS but the grub.conf net defined all the kernel only one new in grub.conf